# ANT - regex in headfilter

Tags: svn, ant, build

First of all I am very new to ANT and I researched a lot about the problem I am facing but didnt get any success. 
I am trying to get SVN revision no. by the following ant task. I got the revision no. but I guess there is a new line in that revision number. When I append that number to artifact I see ? in that.

`<target name="revision-number" >`
   `<loadfile srcfile="${basedir}/projectName/.svn/entries" property="revision">` 
       `<filterchain>` 
          `<headfilter lines="1" skip="3"/>`
       `</filterchain>`
   `</loadfile>`
   `<echo file="REVISION" message="${revision}"/>`
  `</target>`

ZIP logic goes here.

when I see the name in unix terminal it shows - projectName.12345?.tar.gz
and in winscp name is correct - projectName.12345.tar.gz

logs 
      [echo]  Start Zip 
      [tar] Building tar: /opt/maven/hudson/jobs/project/workspace/projectName.tar
     [gzip] Building: /opt/maven/hudson/jobs/project/workspace/projectName.156308
     [gzip] .tar.gz
     [echo]  Stop Zip

There are two [gzip]

I am getting error while copying .gz file using winscp  (error code 123)
so I want to strip this new line.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use `trim`, `IgnoreBlank` or `DeleteCharacters` filter to do this. More information is here:

trim: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#trim

IgnoreBlank: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#IgnoreBlank

DeleteCharacters: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#DeleteCharacters